# Explore a matrix with undefined size

Tags: c++, matrix, graph

I am trying to explore an environment by modelling it with 2 dimensional matrix. However, I don't know the size of the matrix beforehand.

Currently, I am using std::vector< std::vector > structure to abstract the matrix and resize it to certain size. If my application reaches the limit of my original resize, I do that operation again.

I am exploring this matrix with a combination of DFS and A* algorithms. My explorer agent can move forward, backward, left and right. Every time the explorer reaches a position, he adds the neighbors to the stack of DFS. For example, if he is at position (25, 25), it will add the neighbors (25,24), (25, 26), (24, 25) and (26, 25).

So far, it has worked properly. However, there is a scenario that I did not thought. I was always testing my algorithm with the explorer beginning at a corner of the matrix, which behaves great. But, if the explorer starts at the middle of the room or any other position that is not in a corner, my algorithm does not work properly.

That happens because I start my explorer at position 0,0 in the matrix. Therefore, if the explorer begins at the middle of the room, some positions would not be explored, because they would generate negative index for my explorer. Does anyone has any idea of what I can do in order to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simplify it like you said and force it to start from a corner.

The more complicated way would be to, whenever you encounter an index that WOULD be negative, resize the array and all indexes previously generated to force them positive. For performance, probably in large chunks, like simply adding 10 or 100 to everything.

So you add a check for negative numbers when you go to add neighbors and if any of them are negative you apply the same addition to all indexes you've generated so far to force every index positive.

It's just an imaginary coordinate system, the important part is their relative positions. At the end, decide which one should be 0,0 and subtract enough from x,y from it and ALL indexes to normalize the vector back.

Also a performance concern, if you start from a large enough positive number, you may be able to reduce or eliminate the need for this coordinate map shifting until the very end. Like if you start from 100,100 then you would need to travel 100 nodes before you got negative. If there were less than 100 nodes in any direction, you wouldn't have to translate until you've completed mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have thought on using your approach, however, replacing vector for map kind of solved this issue. The only problem now is to print my matrix properly with the map structure.